# pyodbc and special characters in folder path during insert

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I want to gather all pdf files in a folder and insert them in to a MSSQL Table. It works on Query Editor but since there are lots of files it needs to be scripted but i have a problem on special characters in folder paths like ö, ş, ı, ü, ğ. They appear correctly on print outputs but during insertion it gives error like below.

```
from glob import glob
import os, os.path
import pyodbc

encoding = 'utf-8'

files = []
customers = []
paths = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Sync Folder\Customers"):
    for f in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
        if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == '.pdf':
            if "OLD" not in fullpath:
                files.append(f)
                customers.append(fullpath.split('/')[-1])
                paths.append(fullpath)

for i in range(0, len(customers)):
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DSN;UID=sa;PWD=PWD;DATABASE=DB')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PDF_TABLE(FILE, CUSTOMER) VALUES((SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '{0}', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB), '{1}')".format(paths[i],
customers[i]))
```

And the error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native 
Client 11.0][SQL Server] 
"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Sync Folder\\Customers\\xxx S�STEM\\14.03.2017  \'
AND xxx PROJES�.pdf" dosyas� yok. (4860) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

? marks are visible correctly on print outputs.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a manifestation of [this issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/251) which has been fixed in the pyodbc source but has not yet been pushed out in an official release.

Comment: BTW, this question was also asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/292).